# how to identify the breed of a turtle within a dynamic agentset by using a foreach loop in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to scan all the turtles in the vicinity of a turtle and if they are eligible, and if the ratios of the different breeds within a cluster of size greater than 10 turtles is okay, then I link the turtle up with the leader of the cluster.

But I am having trouble identifying the breed of each item within the agentset 'candidates', which is a list of all turtles within the vicinity of the turtle I am asking. According to the breed of the item/turtle, I want to execute a command block.

Can anyone help please?

```
let candidates turtles in-radius radius_scan with [ leader != [leader] of myself and exempt_from_immobilisation = false and aggregated = false]
          
          if (any? candidates) ;; if there are candidates around and the cluster is too small, then proceed to increase the size of the cluster without taking into account any ratios
          [
            ifelse 
            length(aggregate-list) < 10 [
              if who not member? aggregate-list [ set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list ]
              create-links-with candidates [show-link ]
              ask candidates [
                set aggregated true
                if who not member? aggregate-list [ set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list ]
                ;set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list
                merge ]
            ]
            [ ;; if cluster is big enough, start checking if the ratios are approximately making sense
              
              (foreach candidates [ t ->
                ;let t-breed breed of t
                (ifelse 
                  
                  breed = sykfactive   [
                    ifelse (  ( (length(filter is-monomer1? aggregate-list)) + (length(filter is-dimer2? aggregate-list)) + (length(filter is-monomer2syk1active_crosslink? aggregate-list))) <= ( (length(filter is-sykfactive? aggregate-list)) + 5 ))
                    [
                      if who not member? aggregate-list [ set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list ]
                      create-links-with t [show-link ]
                      ask t [
                        set aggregated true
                        if who not member? aggregate-list [ set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list ]
                        ;set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list
                        merge ]
                      
                    ]
                    [;;else commands
                      print "nothing to print or do"
                    ]
                    
                  ]
                
                is-monomersykactive?  [
                  if ( (length(filter is-monomersykactive? aggregate-list)) <= ( (length(filter is-monomer1? aggregate-list)) + 5 ))
                  [
                    if who not member? aggregate-list [ set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list ]
                    create-links-with t [show-link ]
                    ask t [
                      set aggregated true
                      if who not member? aggregate-list [ set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list ]
                      ;set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list
                      merge ]
                    
                  ]
                ]
                
                is-dimer2syk1active? [ 
                  if ( ( (length(filter is-monomer1? aggregate-list)) + (length(filter is-dimer2? aggregate-list)) ) >= ( (length(filter is-dimer2syk1active? aggregate-list) + 5 )) )
                    [
                      if who not member? aggregate-list [ set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list ]
                      create-links-with t [show-link ]
                      ask t [
                        set aggregated true
                        if who not member? aggregate-list [ set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list ]
                        ;set aggregate-list lput myself aggregate-list
                        merge ]
                      
                    ]
                    ]
                  
                  [;;else commands
                    print "nothing to print or do"
                  ])
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  ]
                )
                
                
                
              
            ]
          ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't work out what all the filtering and merging is supposed to do so I can't fix your code directly. Breed is a variable of the turtle in the same way as any other attribute, so I would `count` the different breeds and store that in local variables, then use the local variables for the if/then decisions.

Something like (assumes there are two breeds called breedA and breedB):

```
if any? candidates
[ let numA count candidates with [breed = breedA]
  let numB count candidates with [breed = breedB]
  if numA < numB / 2
  [ print "A is rare here"
  ]
]
```

If you want to do something specifically with the different candidate types, then you can subset candidates by breed and do the counting after:

```
if any? candidates
[ let candidatesA candidates with [breed = breedA]
  let numA count candidatesA
  let candidatesB candidates with [breed = breedB]
  let numB count candidatesB
  if numA < numB / 2
  [ ask candidatesA
    [ set color red
    ]
  ]
]
```